# $|G|=24$ prove that $G$ is not simple

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order 24, and we shall assume there there exist a non-normal 2-sylow group in $G$. i want to show that it's not simple.

first i have showed that there are exactly three 2-sylow group's.

and now i am trying to show that there is a non trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $S_3$. i know that $S_3\cong D_3$  and indeed there are three 2-sylow groups in $D_3$ , the reflection's. and there is one $3-$sylow group in $D_3$  so i wanted to creat a homomorphism that take the different p-sylow groups in $G$  and set them in right $p-$sylow group's in $D_3$  but for that i need to show that the intersection of every two $2-$sylow gouts in $G$  is trivial. and i can't manage to do that....

Comment: you are right i edited the question. thanks

Comment: If there is a non-trivial homomorphism to $S_3$ the kernel is a normal subgroup. And there is because the Sylow theorems tell us that the Sylow subgroups of order $3$ are permuted transitively by conjugation in the main group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple group $G$ of order $24$ would have three Sylow $2$-subgroups, and
so there would be a non-trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $S_3$ (see the comment) which will be injective by simplicity and therefore $24$ would divide $6$ which is absurd.

Comment: I would like to know why the homomorphism from $G$ to $S_3$ is injective

Comment: Because if it was not injective, it would have a non-trivial kernel, which would be a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$. But $G$ is assumed to be simple...

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can you just explain, how does the non trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $S_3$ exist ?, I am not much clear from the OP too.

Comment: @MessiLio $G$ acts (transitively) on the set of $2$-Sylow subgroups by conjugation. Since there's $3$ of them, we obtain a group action of $G$ on a set of size $3$. Thus the action gives us a non-trivial homomorphism $G \to S_3$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n_2=1$ we are done. If $n_2=3$, then the intersection of the Sylow $2$-subgroups is normal (it's the normal core in $G$ of any of them); so, if such intersection is non-trivial, then we are done again; on the other hand, if it is trivial, then the two elements left out of the $2$-Sylow's must be the nontrivial elements of the unique $3$-Sylow, which is then normal. So, in any case there is a nontrivial, proper, normal subgroup of $G$, which is then non-simple.